# How do I check out/in items from a custom list?

Tags: sharepoint, checkout, nintex-workflow

I want to create a library type application with nintex. I want to be able to check out/in "books", and have columns that say if its available for check-out or not. I want it to also contain the dates of checkout.

Now, I'm pretty sure I want a custom list for this but am having problems checking it out because it doesn't give me the option to say "current item" from the "Checkout From: "  drop down list. (as it does in the manual: http://nintexdownload.com/sl/supportfiles/NintexWorkflow2007UserManual.pdf ). I've googled this and found a posting about how you can not check out items from a custom list. Am I going about this the wrong way?

I'm completely new and this is a training project to learn how to use it but I am completely lost. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in/check out are only available for documents. You do not need to check in/check out list items because you can directly change their values from the workflow.

I misunderstood how this worked, thought I'd share if anybody else ran into the same thing. Good luck!